# Geodesate extract angles and edges length of a polyhedron

Tags: geodesy, polyhedra

I'm using Mathematica 11, don't have access to new functions in Geodesate.

**Edited to clarify my question**

What I aim to do, it is to extract the angles and length of edges of a polyhedron (also in the case of geodesic polyhedrons, where edges are not regular).

Example:

```
PolyhedronData["Icosidodecahedron", "Net"]
```

I want to extract the angles and length of edges of the "planar" map.

[image]

How could I manipulate this object?

As second step, I want to extract the same properties for a geodesic polyhedron [GP]:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron
```

So for example, consider this GP:

```
Graphics3D[
 First[PolyhedronOperations`Geodesate[
   PolyhedronData["GreatRhombicosidodecahedron"] , 2]],
 SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> Pi/8
 ]
```

While a regular polyhedron has edges lentgh constant:

```
PolyhedronData["GreatRhombicosidodecahedron"]
```

[image]

a geodesic polyhedron obtained from regular polygons may not have regular edges - better said, it can have more than one class of regular edges, see in the pictures a class of edges common to equilateral triangles and squares, a class of isoscele triangles within the squares and another class within of isoscele within the octagon:

[image]

How could I use the `GraphicsComplex` object to extract the "Net" of it?

Example:

```
PolyhedronData[First[PolyhedronOperations`Geodesate[PolyhedronData[
    "GreatRhombicosidodecahedron"] , 2], "Net"]]
```

[image]

I am looking for a way to get the "Net" of a geodesic polyhedron, and to extract the length of its edges and angle between them.

---

Answer (score 3):

By construction all polygons are [*regular*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon). So, edge lengths are all `1`:

```
pnet = PolyhedronData["Icosidodecahedron", "Net"];

MinMax @ Cases[Normal[pnet], p_Polygon :> (N[RegionMeasure[Line @ #]] & /@ 
     Partition[p[[1]], 2, 1, 1]), All]
```

> {1., 1.}

Angles can be obtained using [`PolygonAngle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolygonAngle.html):

```
DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[Normal[pnet], p_Polygon :> N @ PolygonAngle[p], All]
```

> {{1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 
>     1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 
>     1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 
>     1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.0472, 
>     1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 
>     1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 
>     1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 
>     1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.88496, 
>     1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 
>     1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 
>     1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 
>     1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 
>     1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496, 
>     1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}, {1.88496, 1.88496, 
>     1.88496, 1.88496, 1.88496}, {1.0472, 1.0472, 1.0472}}

You can do something similar working with `"NetGraph"` (instead of `"Net"`):

```
ng = PolyhedronData["Icosidodecahedron", "NetGraph"];
```

[image]

Get neighbors, edge lengths, and angles for each vertex:

```
f = {#, AdjacencyList[ng, #], ## & @@ 
    Transpose[({ArcLength[Line@N@#], VectorAngle @@ N[#]} &@
         PropertyValue[{ng, #}, VertexCoordinates]) & /@ 
      Thread[{#, AdjacencyList[ng, #]}]]} &;

vertex = 5;
f @ vertex
```

> {5, {1, 3, 10}, {1., 1., 1.}, {0.407294, 0.00766817, 0.327627}}

Comment: hi @kglr thank you for dedicating time to the question: I updated it for clarity. Your answer is valid for regular polyhedron, but I want to calculate the length of edges also for geodesic ones. I wish I could extract the NetGraph for geodesic polyhedrons, I cannot having a `PolyhedronData` error. As example, in my question, I tried `PolyhedronData[First[PolyhedronOperations`Geodesate[PolyhedronData[
    "GreatRhombicosidodecahedron"] , 2], "Net"]] `